# Como fazer um gerador de texto de acordo com as possibilidades que eu coloco nele

Tags: python

Estou procurando há uns dias sobre como combinar um texto aleatóriamente de acordo com as possibilidades que eu colocar dentro dos parentêses.
Exemplo: (Olá, Oi, Boa tarde) como vai você (o seu dia está ótimo?, a quanto tempo!!!) 
Minha dúvida é: como faço pra gerar um texto diferente com uma das possibilidades que tem ali dentro do parênteses, aquilo que está fora é para permanecer igual. Alguém me da uma luzzzzzzzzzzzz, to tentando em python

Comment: Os textos entre parenteses pertencem já à *string* ou eles podem estar em estruturas diferentes, como uma tupla?

Comment: se você usar um array e colocar para puxar um valor aleatório todas as vezes não daria certo? Usa a data do dia..o horário ..algo do tipo, põe em uma conta matemática..dependendo do número que cair, vai aparecer uma mensagem.

Answer (score 4):

O Python possui uma função nativa para isso: [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

```
from random import choice

saudacoes = ('Olá', 'Oi', 'Boa tarde')
saudacao = choice(saudacoes)

print(f'{saudacao}, como vai você?')
```

Desta forma, toda vez que o código for executado, uma *string* de `saudacoes` será escolhida aleatoriamente.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muitoooooooooooo obrigado, não tinha aprendido essa parte ainda, tava fazendo uma gambiarra das braba aqui e não tava dando certo. Vlw mesmo

Answer (score -1):

Coloque as opções dentro de uma tupla, embaralhe com o método random.shuffle, e pegue a primeira posição.

```
from random import shuffle

op1 = ['Olá', 'Oi', 'Boa tarde']
shuffle(op1)

op2 = ['o seu dia está ótimo?', 'a quanto tempo!!!']
shuffle(op2)

print "{} como vai você {}".format(op1[0], op2[0])
```

dessa forma, as frases vão mudar, automaticamente

Comment: Para clarificar, eu votei contra por não perceber vantagens em utilizar a biblioteca `random`, mas não utilizar a função `choice`, que foi implementada para resolver este problema.

Comment: Mas é uma opção que funciona, e atenderia a necessidade do Wagner Rosa, então não vejo porque votar contra. Isso só desencoraja quem quer ajudar aqui. :-(

Comment: Não se sinta desencorajado. Você colaborou e recebeu críticas. Isso acontecerá a todo momento, tente aproveitá-las de uma forma construtiva e você crescerá junto com a comunidade. Uma solução, só porque funciona, não significa que *possa* ser utilizada. A função `suffle` não foi implementada para isso, então muitos que lerão o código irão achar estranho, o que torna o código não claro; afeta o desempenho, pois embaralhar todos os valores sempre que precisar de um novo não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Eu testei aqui e ambas funcionaram perfeitamente, entretando a função choice ficou perfeito para o meu proposito, muito obrigado RickADT e Anderson pelo aprendizado.